# How handle when mouse leaves form during drag and drop

Tags: vb.net

I have my form set up to be able to drop files into a textbox, and also drag the files out of the textbox, thus clearing the textbox. The kicker is that the drag out of the textbox has to be dropped on the form. If I try to drag it outside the form, then it crashes. I would like for the drag and drop to ignore when the mouse is moved outside of the form. Any ideas? Here's the error I get when I drag the file out of the textbox and out of the form:

Invalid FORMATETC structure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040064 (DV_E_FORMATETC))

Comment: The error you are getting tells you that the data object doesn't comply with the format you use for it. It is impossible to guess what's actually going wrong without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the cursor inside of the form. [Cursor.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip.aspx)

MouseDown event:

```
Cursor.Clip = Me.RectangleToScreen(Me.ClientRectangle)
```

MouseUp Event:

```
Cursor.Clip = Nothing
```

Comment: Is this supposed to not allow the mouse to leave the form?

Comment: From the provided link: A clipped cursor is allowed to move only within its clipping rectangle.

Comment: Well the thought is you get the error if you leave the form, so don't allow the cursor to leave the form - right?

Comment: `Cursor.Clip` is in **screen** coords so you use `Me.RectangleToScreen(Me.ClientRectangle)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @Idle_Mind, it has been awhile since I have used it.